# Connect to Remote MySQL Server as Root over SSH Tunnel

Tags: sql, workbench, ssh-tunnel

I have opened a SSH tunnel to my MySQL server with the following command

`ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 myuser@myhost -vv`

In Workbench I open a new connection to localhost:3307 and test the connection. I'm promted for the Root password, which I enter, then it tells me the parameters are correct.

When I go to save the connection I get the error...

`Exception caught while processing action from home screen: error calling Python module function WbAdmin.autoDetectLocalInstance`

Is this a probllem with Workbench or my Tunnel? How do I resolve it? I feel like I'm so close. The desired outcome is so that I can securely administer my remote MySQL database with Workbench.

Other info...

- MySQL Server is Windows 7
- SSH server is on the MySQL machine and is Cygwin
- Workbench client is on OSX
- I also tried to use Workbench to make the tunnel (New Connection -> SSH etc.). I ran into problems there with it telling me my server OS wasn't windows, which was a lie:)

Comment: Why so complicated? What manually maintain a tunnel? The mysql workbench already implements that feature by itself. Just choose "Standard TCP/IP over SSH" as a connection method and you get the same.

Comment: Would be nice, and if you could help that would be amazing. But see my last point in "Other info". I tried that and couldn't connect.

Comment: Sorry, works for me without a problem, though of course as most others here I use linux as OS. But actually I do not see what this has to do with the operating system of the server: the server seen and used is a ssh server, it is irrelevant on what OS is runs.

Comment: Ha ha, you know what. After restarting Workbench it too is now accepting connections over SSH (i.e its own tunnel). FTW. - Yes the OS error was weird. All working now though.

Comment: It's 'for the win'. But I like the way you said it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK turns out that the connection was saved. In spite of the error, closing and reopening Workbench showed the saved connection and allowed me to connect. It must be a bug in Workbench or something.

Furthermore I can also tunnel using the SSH connection in Workbench since the restart.